# iPhone core data: How to pass and fetch Entities between NIBS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have core data entity: "mole,"  which I display in a TableView.  When I select each in turn, I pass the selected mole to the next NIB using ...

```
controller.mole = [moleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // pass the relevant mole to next NIB
```

When second NIB loads, I want to retrieve just the "details" for just the "mole" selected.  I am using the following:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [mole managedObjectContext]; // find details for the selected mole

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

// now sort

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"detailsDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];

// Having created a fetch request, you now execute it. The events array needs to be mutable, so make a mutable copy of the result.

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {

    NSLog(@"details mutableFetchResults = nil");

}

// The final steps are to set the view controller’s events array instance variable and to release objects that were allocated.

[self setDetailsArray:mutableFetchResults];
[mutableFetchResults release];
[request release];
```

Trouble is the "detailsArray" is returning the Details of *all* the Moles.  I cannot seem to retrieve the Details for just the specific Mole selected.  I presume setting "context" is incorrect.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the `Mole` entity have a to-many relationship with `Details`? If so, you can traverse that relationship and not have to execute a fetch request. Let's say you do have such a relationship and that it's called `details`. You can do this:

```
NSSet *details = [mole valueForKey:@"details"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"detailsDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *detailsArray = [details sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
// [sortDescriptor release];  if you're not using ARC
```

The trick is that relationships are modeled as `NSSet` objects, so you'll still need to sort the value to get an ordered array.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're not filtering the search over your Details entity. You should make a NSPredicate with the mole id (or some kind of identifier) of the mole you passed to the next controller to filter that search and only get the mole you want

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"moleID == %@", mole.id];
```

Something like that, hope this helps.

Comment: Another possible solution is, if you have a relationship between your Mole and Details entities, you can retrieve just the detail managed object from the mole. In your new controller doing something like NSManagedObject *detail = mole.detail; assuming it's a 1-1 relationship, having a 1-N relationship could change a little.

Comment: Hi Herz. It is a one-to-many relationship i.e. one mole object can have n detail objects.  Somehow I want to retrieve all the detail objects for a specific mole

Comment: Then you can do it with a NSSet like someone just said downhere: NSSet *details=[mole valueForKey:@"details"]; and then you can use NSSet methods to retrieve a NSArray or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Mole` managed object already in hand, you don't need a fetch to find it's related `Detail` objects. Instead you just walk the relationship.

It sounds like you have a data model something like this:

```
Mole{
  //.. some attributes
  details<-->>Detail.mole
}

Detail{
  //... some attributes
  mole<<-->Mole.details
}
```

If you have a custom NSManagedObject subclass, then you would just use `aMole.details` to get a set of its related details:

```
NSSet *details=aMoleObj.details;
```

If your just using generic NSManagedObjects, then you would use:

```
NSSet *details=[aMoleObj valueForKey:@"details"];
```

Fetches are always for finding an object you don't have a relationship for. If you already have a related object in hand, you just query the relationship.

Comment: Hi TechZen.  Mole and Details are separate Entities, and it is a one-to-many relationship i.e. n details to each mole.  In that case, is it NSSet details = mole?  Thanks again.